# Is it possible to include a variable inside of a vector3?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, levels

I trying to make a game kind of like slope, where there are new obstacles every 3 seconds.
Instead of making infinite spawn points, I thought of making the first one and change the z by 20 pixels. the problem is I don't know how I can make a Vector3 storing 2 integers and a variable.

I'm kind of stuck so I haven't tried anything since I don't know what to try.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class levelgen : MonoBehaviour

{
    private int count = 9;
    public GameObject[] templates;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        public Vector3 spawn = new Vector3(-2, 0, count);
        int rand = Random.RandomRange(1, 5); //1-5 types of levels
        Instantiate(templates[rand], spawn1, Quaternion.identity);
        count = count + 20;

    }
}
```

I want to store the variable count in the Vector3 spawn.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Which variable do you want to store? Why?

Comment: How do you mean storing a variable? Do you want to pass a variable's contents to `Vector3` constructor?

Comment: I want the vector3 spawn, to look like this Vector3(-2, 0, count)

Comment: You could store `spawn` as a member of your `levelgen` class.  (where you have declared `count` and `templates`) And then you don't need `count`.  You just initialize `span = new Vector(-2, 0, 9)` and instead of incrementing `count` you can do `spawn = spawn + new Vector(0, 0, 20)` Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you *can* .. but it will not be called `count` anymore but e.g. `z`

```
public class levelgen : MonoBehaviour
{
    // You can not declare a public field within a method
    // so move it to class scope
    public Vector3 spawn = new Vector3(-2, 0, 9);
    public GameObject[] templates;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Here NOTE that for int parameters the second argument is "exclusiv"
        // so if you want correct indices you should always rather use
        int rand = Random.RandomRange(0, templates.Length);
        // I will just assume a typo and use spawn instead of spawn1
        Instantiate(templates[rand], spawn, Quaternion.identity);

        spawn.z += 20;

        // Or I would prefer since this works in general
        // Vector3.forward is a shorthand for writing new Vector3(0, 0, 1)
        // and this works in general
        spawn += Vector3.forward * 20;

        // you can e.g. NOT use
        //transform.position.z += 20
        // but only
        //transform.position += Vector3.forward * 20;
    }
}
```

**Note** Having this code `Instantiate` a new object **every frame** in general is a very bad idea. If you really need so many objects checkout [Object Pooling](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling)

Comment: how will Vector3.forward know that it is the z cordinate i want to change?

Comment: because [`Vector3.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-forward.html) equals `new Vector(0, 0, 1)`

Comment: updated it .. you can as well use `spawn.z += 20` if this is better readable for you

Answer (score 2):

You can't store anything else into the Vector3 or any other built in variables*. You can, and you should make custom containers for your variables like classes or structs

```
public struct Custom
{
    int a;
    int b;
    string name;
    int count;
}
```

or something like

```
public struct Custom
{
    Vector3 vec;
    int count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you want to change the z-axis for a new spawn you will need to reassign it to your `Vector3` variable.  You could do this in a for loop as seen below.

`zPosition` in this case is storing the latest zPosition value so you don't need to store it anywhere else. If you want to spawn more obstacles after the initial 10 then it will pick up from the `zPosition` where it left off.

```
public class levelgen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] templates;
    public Vector3 spawn;
    int zPosition = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        GenerateObstacles(10);
    }

    void GenerateObstacles (int numObstacles)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numObstacles; i++)
        {
            spawn = new Vector3(-2, 0, zPosition);
            int rand = Random.Range(0, 6); //1-5 types of levels
            Instantiate(templates[rand], spawn, Quaternion.identity);
            zPosition += 20;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it spawned multiple templates at the same position.

Comment: @StefanMelchior I just realized i accidentally had `spawn1` instead of `spawn` in the Instantiate line. Perhaps that will fix it for you.

Comment: i made 7 level types and changed it to (0, 6)

Comment: @StefanMelchior (0,6) will generate random values from 0 to 5. You will want to use (0,7) to generate values 0 through 6 which covers your 7 levels.